# How can I filter nested field in AgularJS ng-table?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have a structure like:

```
"name": {
    "en": "English Name",
    "tr": "Turkish Name",
    "es": "Spanish Name"
}
```

I want to filter name field.

```
filter="{ 'name.en' : 'text'}"
```

Works fine for "en" field. But I want to filter for all of the fields.

```
filter="{ 'name' : 'text'}" does not work.
```

What should I do?

Comment: No, you cant. Btw, creating custom filter takes 5 minutes...

Comment: How you will set 'en', 'tr'..?